# Want to the check the records existing in the date range in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have the following requirement,

Sample data:

```
Numberid    startDate,          Enddate
---------------------------------------------------    
1900415115  2012-09-22 00:39:00 2013-10-25 00:00:00
2429398311  2008-05-22 16:57:00 2013-07-30 00:00:00
4337719455  2008-05-22 16:57:00 2009-06-12 00:00:00
6644946399  2008-05-22 16:57:00 2009-01-16 00:00:00
9740698857  2008-05-22 16:57:00 2008-09-26 00:00:00
3928192597  2011-08-24 12:14:00 2012-09-24 00:00:00
1233655116  2013-08-14 00:39:00 2013-12-09 00:00:00
1780419233  2008-10-22 00:08:00 2014-08-24 00:00:00
1912939738  2011-08-26 01:32:00 2014-06-20 00:00:00
3810216146  2008-05-22 16:57:00 2009-01-16 00:00:00
5851814815  2009-10-07 01:00:00 2010-01-25 00:00:00
3692916726  2008-05-22 16:57:00 2008-10-02 00:00:00
3069490750  2008-05-22 16:57:00 2009-08-14 00:00:00
```

I want to check if the 'numberid' exists in date range and want to group by

```
01/01/2008 - 01/01/2009 as 0809
01/01/2009 - 01/01/2010 as 0910
01/01/2010 - 01/01/2011 as 1011
01/01/2011 - 01/01/2012 as 1112
```

Appreciate your quick help!!

Thanks,

---

can you try with the following data as im not sure it works for enddate null values

```
Numberid    startDate,          Enddate
--------------------------------------------------- 
4405598510  2011-08-06 00:00:00 NULL
2418680054  2011-08-06 00:00:00 2011-12-28 00:00:00
4405598510  2011-08-06 00:00:00 NULL
1810168034  2011-08-06 00:00:00 NULL
6849266569  2011-08-06 00:00:00 2014-09-02 00:00:00
2682265222  2011-08-09 00:58:00 2012-09-20 00:00:00
6253123963  2011-08-09 00:00:00 2011-07-01 00:00:00
8276745680  2011-08-10 00:00:00 2014-06-27 00:00:00
3873103800  2011-08-10 00:00:00 2013-07-16 00:00:00
3703761027  2011-08-06 00:00:00 NULL
1810168034  2011-08-06 00:00:00 NULL
9888909217  2011-08-08 00:00:00 2013-06-30 00:00:00
3034945061  2011-08-09 00:59:00 NULL
4822850747  2011-08-10 00:00:00 2012-08-21 00:00:00
5849710101  2011-08-10 00:00:00 NULL
```

and also its not yearly 2008, 2009.. 2012..
i need specific dates please.

thanks

Comment: Can you provide expected output?

Comment: else i want to know.. if the numberid exists between the specific ranges yes or no and the columns may be like numberid, actualstartdate, actualenddate, exists0809(y/n), exists0910(y/n), exists1011(y/n), exists1112(y/n)

Comment: Check the Edit for the "specific dates"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
with myTable (
    numberid,
    startDate,
    endDate
) as(
    select
        numberid,
        CONVERT(DATETIME,startDate),
        CONVERT(DATETIME,endDate)
    from (
    values
        (4405598510,'2011-08-06 00:00:00',NULL),
        (2418680054,'2011-08-06 00:00:00','2011-12-28 00:00:00'),
        (4405598510,'2011-08-06 00:00:00',NULL),
        (1810168034,'2011-08-06 00:00:00',NULL),
        (6849266569,'2011-08-06 00:00:00','2014-09-02 00:00:00'),
        (2682265222,'2011-08-09 00:58:00','2012-09-20 00:00:00'),
        (6253123963,'2011-08-09 00:00:00','2011-07-01 00:00:00'),
        (8276745680,'2011-08-10 00:00:00','2014-06-27 00:00:00'),
        (3873103800,'2011-08-10 00:00:00','2013-07-16 00:00:00'),
        (3703761027,'2011-08-06 00:00:00',NULL),
        (1810168034,'2011-08-06 00:00:00',NULL)
    ) [ ] (numberid,startDate,endDate)
)
select
    Numberid,
    startDate,
    endDate,
    case when 2009 between year(startDate) and ISNULL(year(endDate),year(startDate)) then 'y' else 'n' end [0809],
    case when 2010 between year(startDate) and ISNULL(year(endDate),year(startDate)) then 'y' else 'n' end [0910],
    case when 2011 between year(startDate) and ISNULL(year(endDate),year(startDate)) then 'y' else 'n' end [1011],
    case when 2012 between year(startDate) and ISNULL(year(endDate),year(startDate)) then 'y' else 'n' end [1112],
    case when 2013 between year(startDate) and ISNULL(year(endDate),year(startDate)) then 'y' else 'n' end [1213]
from myTable
```

Edit:

you can do, instead of:

```
2009 between year(startDate) and ISNULL(year(endDate),year(startDate))
```

So you can setup the interval, this:

```
case when startDate <= '2012-01-01' and ISNULL(endDate,startDate) >= '2011-01-01' then 'y' else 'n' end [1011],
```

Comment: ok let me make it simple here.. i want to get the numberid that exists in this date range 01/01/2009 - 01/01/2010 as 0910..  among its start and end dates.

Comment: You should always add to your questions expected output, and i'm not just talking about the Column. With your provided Sample data what is the output.

Comment: I apologize.. Solution given second is helpful to some extent but it is not working when i have as enddata as null ex: 9740698857,'2008-05-22 16:57:00','null', its not showing up, my consideration is it should have shown in  in 2008 year as 'y' thaks again!! as an example  1043085226 2014-08-19 22:35:00 NULL n n n n n

7573180793 2008-05-22 16:57:00 NULL n n n n n

1059281603 2014-09-01 22:24:00 NULL n n n n n

1059281603 2014-09-01 22:24:00 NULL n n n n n

1105021936 2012-09-13 02:12:00 NULL n n n n n

Comment: Please add that information to the Question.

Comment: can you try with this set of data, bcoz.. 4405598510 2011-08-06 00:00:00 NULL
2418680054 2011-08-06 00:00:00 2011-12-28 00:00:00
4405598510 2011-08-06 00:00:00 NULL
1810168034 2011-08-06 00:00:00 NULL
6849266569 2011-08-06 00:00:00 2014-09-02 00:00:00
2682265222 2011-08-09 00:58:00 2012-09-20 00:00:00
6253123963 2011-08-09 00:00:00 2011-07-01 00:00:00
8276745680 2011-08-10 00:00:00 2014-06-27 00:00:00
3873103800 2011-08-10 00:00:00 2013-07-16 00:00:00
3703761027 2011-08-06 00:00:00 NULL
1810168034 2011-08-06 00:00:00 NULL

Comment: Add that to the question for formating purposes.